# drop down menu disappears on hover (blogger)

Tags: css, blogger

I'll be honest right off the bat, I am not a coder. I got the original code for this from a tutorial and just tweaked the colors and fonts, but when I hover on the main menu item and try to click the sub-menu, it vanishes. I see from other threads this is a common problem, but I can't seem to find a previously asked question with code like mine.

```
/**MBW mybloggersworld.com Navgation bar **/
#mbwnavbar {
background: #ffffff;
width: 960px;
color: #FFF;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
border-top:0px solid #ffffff;
height:35px;
}
#mbwnav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#mbwnav ul {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#mbwnav li {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
border-right:1px solid #ffffff;
height:35px;
}
#mbwnav li a, #mbwnav li a:link, #mbwnav li a:visited {
color: #000000;
display: block;
font:bold 16px Coming Soon;    margin: 0;
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
text-decoration: none;

}
#mbwnav li a:hover, #mbwnav li a:active {
background: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;

}
#mbwnav li {
float: left;
padding: 0;
}
#mbwnav li ul {
z-index: 9999;
position: absolute;
left: -999em;
height: auto;
width: 160px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#mbwnav li ul a {
width: 140px;
}
#mbwnav li ul ul {
margin: -25px 0 0 161px;
}
#mbwnav li:hover ul ul, #mbwnav li:hover ul ul ul, #mbwnav li.sfhover ul ul, #mbwnav
li.sfhover ul ul ul {
left: -999em;
}
#mbwnav li:hover ul, #mbwnav li li:hover ul, #mbwnav li li li:hover ul, #mbwnav 
li.sfhover ul, #mbwnav li li.sfhover ul, #mbwnav li li li.sfhover ul {
left: auto;
}
#mbwnav li:hover, #mbwnav li.sfhover {
position: static;
}
#mbwnav li li a, #mbwnav li li a:link, #mbwnav li li a:visited 
{
background: #ffffff;
width: 120px;
color: #000000;
display: block;
font:normal 12px Coming Soon;
margin: 0;
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
z-index:1010;
border-bottom:0px dotted #ffffff;

}
#mbwnav li li a:hover, #mbwnavli li a:active {
background: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
display: block;     margin: 0;
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any idea how to make the submenu stay long enough for someone without super human speed to click a submenu?

Please and thank you :)

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show the relevant HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: Don't comment with the code, edit your post and add your code to it.  Wrap your code in `brackets` by using the { } button.  @siva.k OP can use jsfiddle but should show relevant code here too.

Comment: Ah, the bracket thing probably would have been faster than going through and adding 4 spaces to every line once I realized it was too long for comment lol I hope I did that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing your html to test, it's very difficult to guess, but try changing:

```
#mbwnav li:hover ul, #mbwnav li li:hover ul, #mbwnav li li li:hover ul, #mbwnav 
li.sfhover ul, #mbwnav li li.sfhover ul, #mbwnav li li li.sfhover ul {
left: auto;
}
```

to

```
#mbwnav li:hover ul, #mbwnav li li:hover ul, #mbwnav li li li:hover ul, #mbwnav 
li.sfhover ul, #mbwnav li li.sfhover ul, #mbwnav li li li.sfhover ul {
left: auto; display:block; position:relative;
}
```

you may also need some negative top margin (like margin-top:-5px) but see if this code is of help. If not, please post the html so we can test

Comment: That makes the sub-menu drop down disappear and a white block show to the left of the hovered menu. I didn't see a change when I changed the margin to -5. How do I post the html? Just link the page? [link](http://www.lifewithgremlins.com)

Comment: Got it :) Add this to your CSS:

`#mbwnav li{
left: auto; display:inline; position:relative; top:0px;  z-index:1
}
#mbwnav li:hover > ul, #mbwnav li li:hover > ul, #mbwnav li li li:hover > ul, #mbwnav 
li.sfhover > ul, #mbwnav li li.sfhover > ul, #mbwnav li li li.sfhover > ul {
left: auto; display:inline; position:absolute; top:0px;  z-index:100000; padding-top:40px;
}
#mbwnav li:hover > ul li{position:relative; display:block}`

Comment: Worked :D Thank you. You rock.